# Как реализовать связь EF

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Имеются такие таблицы: `поставщик`, `покупатель`, `работник`. У каждого есть свои личные данные (имя, адрес, телефон, и т.д.). Решил вынести эти данные в отдельную таблицу `Карточка`. Теперь в таблицах `поставщик`, `покупатель`, `работник` находится внешний ключ на таблицу `карточка`.

Как реализовать такую связь средствами C# при помощи EF Code First?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанная вами зависимость называется `One-to-One`

```
public class Worker
{
    public Worker() { }

    public int WorkerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Info Info { get; set; }

}

public class Info 
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Worker")]
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Worker Worker{ get; set; }
}
```

[Тут](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) подробный гайд.

Comment: это у вас Worker и поставщик, и покупатель, и работник?

Comment: Оно серьезно так паршиво выглядит в EF? я пользовался только nhibernate, там id в сущностях не нужны для ссылок.

Comment: @Grundy Нет, Worker, Proveider, Customer имеют FK на таблицу Card.

Comment: @AleksPodp, это вообще был вопрос к отвечающему, потому что у него в инфо так же ссылка на воркера

Comment: @Bezarius если не трудно опишите хотя бы еще 1 класс(Customer). У меня сложность заключалась именно в описании нескольких классов. Спасибо.

Comment: @Monk гляньте гайд, там есть еще FluentApi, это лишь один из вариантов.

Comment: @Aleksandr я давно не работал с EF, но если мне не изменяет память, вы можете просто добавить еще  ForeignKey в инфо для других сущностей и все.

Comment: @Bezarius таки да, спасибо, FluentApi выглядит намного приятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение данной проблемы при помощи Fluent API:

```
 
  public class WorkerCard
  {
        public long Id { get; set; }
```

```
    public long? ContactDetail_Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirthday { get; set; }

    public  ContactDetail ContactDetail { get; set; }
  }

public class UserCard
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? ContactDetail_Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirthday { get; set; }

    public  ContactDetail ContactDetail { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerCard
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? ContactDetail_Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirthday { get; set; }

    public  ContactDetail ContactDetail { get; set; }
}

 public class ContactDetail// Таблица на которую все ссылаются
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public CustomerCard CustomerCards { get; set; }

    public UserCard UserCards { get; set; }

    public WorkerCard WorkerCards { get; set; }
}
```

public class ContextTest : DbContext// Контекст
    {
        public ContextTest()
            : base("name=ContextTest")
        {
        }

public DbSet<ContactDetail> ContactDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerCard> CustomerCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserCard> UserCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkerCard> WorkerCards { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //Fluent API:

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactDetail>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.CustomerCards)
            .WithOptional(e => e.ContactDetail);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactDetail>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.UserCards)
            .WithOptional(e => e.ContactDetail);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactDetail>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.WorkerCards)
            .WithOptional(e => e.ContactDetail);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

Comment: @Bezarius Спасибо Bezarius за гайд.